# "en la nokto" vs "en nokto"

Tags: article

I found the following phrase in an Esperanto textbook:

Ŝi promesis montri al Andreo serion da poŝtkartoj, prezentantaj Bukureŝton en la nokto.

Why there is "la" before "nokto"? It doesn't seem to refer to any particular night, rather is about night views of the city. If it is an idiomatic phrase or "la nokto" refers to a night in general (like in English), can I even make the difference between "during that particular night" and "at night (in general)"? Or maybe it's a mistake and there should be "en nokto" which for me makes more sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The definite article is used in a couple of ways in Esperanto.

## referential use

Referential use means being known by the context.

- *Hej, ĉu vi prenis la librojn kun vi?* : here both the speaker and the listener know which books are we talking about

As Joop Eggen points out here the correlatives *(ĉi) tiu(j)* make it easier to understand especially for speakers of languages which do not have articles.

## generally known and unique

- *La suno brilas kaj la ĉielo bluas.* : the closest sun and the sky of this planet

## categorical use

- *La hundo estas la plej fidela de la bestoj.* : here one dog represent dogs in general, as species

You can think of this kind of use to mean the same as with the correlative *ĉiu(j)*, even if not directly replaceable with it. Your example falls into this category.

Note, that this use can sometimes be hard to distinguish from the referential use.

- *La knabino kuras plej rapide de la infanoj.* : here *la* refers to a particular girl and not girls as a category

## body parts

Depending on your native language the use of the article with body parts can be really confusing.

- *La kapo doloras al mi.* : *la* denotes that we talk about my head

Note, that sometimes the reciever (*al mi*) is omitted, so that when the speaker says *la kapo doloras*, you should understand that they refers to their own head, and to some generally known, unique head somewhere.

## remark

One of the languages Zamenhof spoke natively was Polish which does not have articles, he stated for instance in [*lingva respondo 83B (LR83B)*](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-subresp-83b) that whenever in doubt it is better to leave out the article.

Answer (score 0):

It is a *categorical* usage of `la`:

> Estas multe da karbonhidratoj en **la** pano.

This is however not clear. Out of context it could refer to an earlier occurrence. Clear would be:

> Estas multe da karbonhidratoj en **ĉiu** pano / **ĉiuj** panoj.

One can often do a more normal, more multi-lingual *referential* usage with `tiu`:

> Estas multe da ŝimo en **tiu** pano.

Note that *nokto, pano, akvo* and such are generic notions here. Especially here *nokto* is not just one night, but all nights.

Answer (score 0):

Kiel jam menciis Juha Metsäkallas, tio estas ekzemplo de "referenca uzo". Temas ne pri "iu ajn" nokto, sed pri nokto difinita per kunteksto.
En ĉi kunteksto tio povas esti:

- la/konkreta nokto, pri kiu scias la konversaciantoj - ŝi kaj Andreo; ili povis plani kaj elekti nokton, planita nokto estas jam la nokto;
- la nokto, ligita kun la evento de konversacio, ekzemple, iu el proksimaj tempe - tiu nokto, kiu venos hodiaŭ, sed ne iu el ĉiuj noktoj dum vivo de la konversaciantoj (ŝi kaj Andreo);
- la kunteksto povis jam priskribi iun nokton, kaj per la artikolo estas referencita tiu nokto, pri kiu jam scias ni, kiel legantoj;
  ktp.